# CopyPaste data range values to next empty rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I use every day to generate the day's P&L.
I copy and paste the 13 rows over the bottom of the prior day's P&L.
I want to create a macro that would copy the 13 rows over the next empty cell. I have the code to grab the first row and last row within the data range.

I don't know how to grab the 13 rows, Rows 15 to 27, and past these to the second empty row, Row 29:

[image]

I have this code so far:

```
 Sub PasteValToNextRows()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

   '*****Copy the Rows of Data Range and Paste to next second Empty Row*****

   ''''''Finds the First Row within a Data Range 
   Range("A" & lMaxRows + 0).Offset(-12, 0).EntireRow.Select

   '''''Finds the Last Row within a Data Range
   Range("A" & lMaxRows + 0).EntireRow.Select    

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True

     [![enter image description here][1]][1]End Sub
```

Comment: And next day it will start on row 42? Edit: Scott's gonna beat me to it ^_^;

Comment: Yes. The range is Dynamic, so everyday , the prior days work keeps on being copy down the sheet.

Comment: Scott the 11/13/2015 gets paste to Row 29 and the next day 11/14/2015 gets paste to Row 43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using copy/paste because it looks like you have formatting. Please see comment to reflect the range you need.

```
Sub cemg()

Dim fRow As Long
Dim lRow As Long

With ActiveSheet

    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    fRow = lRow - 12

    .Range(.Cells(fRow, 1), .Cells(lRow, 6)).Copy 'change 6 to the number of columns you have
    .Cells(lRow + 2, 1).PasteSpecial

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not at my usual workstation, I only have the one screen.  So I am slower.  It's like having half my brain on vacation.

Comment: Awww yisss found Scott's kryptonite~

Comment: Yup force me onto a laptop with a mouse pad.

Comment: Didn't you get the memo? Your workstation privileges have been revoked indefinitely. You will be supplied with pencil and paper going forward. I want the 98716114456478912436th digit of pi in an hour.

Comment: guys, if I want to copy the entire row not just the range ,what would i change

Comment: The 6 refers to the column. 6 = F. 7 = G and so forth.